# Modal view controller is slow to appear

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I'm having a hard time debugging an issue when presenting a modal view controller. I'm seeing a pause of between 0.5 seconds and 1 second between viewWillAppear being called and viewDidAppear being called on the presented (table view) controller. I tried replacing this with a bare bones table view controller to see if the issue was in the controller calling presentModalController, and it appeared quickly as expected.

I've peppered both controllers with NSLog statements in an attempt to diagnose the issue, but can't narrow it down further than a delay between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Short of rewriting the controller line by line, what's the best way for me to find out where the issue is? Are there any usual suspects here I should be aware of?

**Edit : update with problematic code**

The table view is displaying 2 cells, each containing a text field.

I have UITextField properties for each of the 2 text fields

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *itemTextField;
```

and assign text fields to these properties as follows :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            textField.delegate = self;

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Item";
            textField.placeholder = @"Enter item name";
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            self.itemTextField = textField;
            [cell addSubview:textField];
            [textField release];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I've left out the second row, but the code is the same.

If I comment out

```
self.itemTextField = textField;
```

the view loads as expected, but uncommented causes the slight delay I've been seeing. Should I be initialising this somewhere else rather than in cellForRowAtIndexPath? I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Not sure why that causes a delay, looks quite normal to me. You don't really need `self.itemTextField = textField;` though. You could give the textField a tag, and find your way back to the textField that way.

Comment: I rewrote it to use tags rather than the property, but still the same problem. I eventually narrowed it down to a becomeFirstResponder call in viewWillAppear (I wanted the keyboard to be available as soon as the view appeared, rather than have the animation). Moving this to viewDidAppear allowed the view to appear quickly, albeit with the unwanted keyboard animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Time Profiler in Instruments to see which is the offending code. Also note that excessive logging itself can cause noticeable speed degradation. Likely cases are costly methods to provide data to your table view, custom heights perhaps? Or loading of content from a network synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the Instruments tip. No custom heights, no pulling data from the network. After some more fiddling around, I think I've pinpointed it to assigning textfields to a property.

Comment: Sorry, hitting return caught me out there. I'll edit the main question with some more code.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. Just fixed it with barrym's comment. Just move the becaomeFirstResponder code to viewDidAppear